# T-SQL - joining a transaction table to an audit table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, audit-trail

Say I have these two tables:

**Transaction Table**

```
Pmt ID    VendorID      PaymentDate
 1             1        2017-10-01 00:14:42
 2             2        2017-09-03 00:08:23
```

The second table has a list of those VendorIDs, and everytime the associated email changed.  It could have changed tons of times.

**Audit Table**

```
VendorID       Email                CreateDateUTC
1              a@gmail.com          2016-01-01 17:51:08
1              b@gmail.com          2016-03-03 12:40:03
1              c@gmail.com          2017-01-10 03:40:04
2              li@gmail.com         2017-03-30 05:40:03
```

Edit:  So say this would show that any payment that went to vendor id 1 after 2016-01-01 17:51:08 but before 2016-03-03 12:40:03 went to a@gmail.com.  Any payment that went to vendor id 1 after 2016-03-03 12:40:03 but before 2017-01-10 03:40:04 went to b@gmail.com.  And that anything to vendor id 1 that went after 2017-01-10 03:40:04 went to c@gmail.com (unless of course, there's another more recent entry for vendor 1 in the Audit Table).

If I say - wanted to know every transaction that went out to email example@gmail.com, how could I query that?

My assumption is I'd take the transaction table - then join the audit table.  Then OK, we have every transaction, and the email it went to.  But, how to join only the correct email?  Or, am I maybe thinking about this the wrong way entirely?

Comment: Your 2017-10-01 transaction was emailed to both a@gmail.com and b@gmail.com?  Or just the latest email address before the transaction date (b@gmail.com)?

Comment: Just the latest address before the transaction date.  Thanks, I wasn't clear!

Answer (score 0):

You Have to create one vendor master in which only main distinct vendor is stored with unique id.
Then create a sub table vendor contact detail.In that add the more than on contact detail for the vendor created in the master and in vendor contact detail also insert one field isPrimary that is bifurcate the Vendor address to be chosen.
then make join and do the task

Answer (score 0):

Need more info, but maybe this will work?

```
select distinct t.PmtID, t.VendorID, t.PaymentDate
from tblTrans t
inner join tblAudit a
on t.VendorID = a.VendorID
where t.PaymentDate <= a.CreateDateUTC
and a.Email = 'a@gmail.com'
order by t.PaymentDate
```

Comment: Thanks.  That would work for finding them one by one.  I'm looking for a way to join every payment with its email though.  Or to at least, be able to answer questions like  'what's every transaction that went out to email example@gmail.com?'

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns all rows from transaction table and it matches audit table and gets the email ID to which the email has been sent at the time of transaction

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT VENDOR.*,Audit.Email,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 
           Vendor.VendorID ORDER BY DATEDIFF(D,CreateDateUTC, PaymentDate) DESC) RNo
   FROM Vendor LEFT OUTER JOIN Audit ON Vendor.VendorId =Audit.VendorId 
   WHERE PaymentDate > CreateDateUTC 
)T
WHERE RNo = 1
```

Comment: Thanks.  That would just work for 1 at a time though, right?

Comment: No...You will get all records in vendor table..Rno = 1 is used to get email id..Can you execute the query with actual data and try?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look closely enough!  Slight modification for T-SQL: 'With <randomname> AS <your query> SELECT * FROM <randomname> WHERE Rno = 1.  Unfortunately,it eventually returns 'The transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full'.  Even when I limit it to TOP (1)!  I suspect because both tables are over 1 million rows...

Comment: ...OK I just got it to return 1 result, by limiting it to Vendor.<one field> instead of Vendor.*   Let me keep on this, thanks!

Comment: It seems to work, but it's only returning a subset from the 'vendor' table.  I didn't have time to try to figure out why (yet).